# Forward to an action in another appliction in same servlet container in struts2

Tags: struts2, forward

I am trying to forward the control to an action class in application B from another action class in application A. Both applications are running in the same servlet container. Here is the code I wrote:

```
    RequestDispatcher rd = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getContext("/App2").getRequestDispatcher("/newApp.action");
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("commonQuestions", answers);
    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    rd.forward(request, response);
    return null;
```

It is returning "404-Resource not found" error. Of course, the same code with slight modification to access an action in the same application 1 works fine. What am doing wrong here?. Thanks in advance!.

Comment: I think there might be security you need to adjust for the application server, what server are you using?

Comment: *Forward*?! You don't forward to other apps, you redirect.

Comment: "404-Resource not found" means that there's no such resource in the application A. Webapps are running isolated from each other, so you can't do it.

Comment: >> Quaternion >> It is glassfish 2.1 server, running on my local desktop. I don't see any security issues.

Comment: >> Dave Newton >> You can forward to other apps.

Comment: >> Roman C >> There is the resource in the other app that works fine when you access from the browser. Yes, web apps run isolated from each other and that is exactly why "forward" and "redirect" APIs are there to make calls to reach the resources either in the same app or other application contexts as well.

Comment: @user2510300 Use **@** tags to reply to individual users. But your understanding of web apps is incorrect; unless you specifically configure some form of session sharing (inherently dangerous), resources are isolated from each other.